# why is pointer to a char behaving differently than a pointer to a char as array element?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am curious why this two chunks of code give different output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char *arr=new char;
    arr="monday";
    cout<<arr<<endl;//gives the output "monday"

    char *newArr=new char[3];//i want array of three pointers not the size of a string to be 2+1
    newArr[0]="monday";//err
    cout<<newArr[0]<<endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

i mean aren't they both pointers to address of first letter

the question is what is the difference between "arr" and "newArr[0]"

Answer (score 5):

You have more trouble than you realize...

With

```
char *arr=new char;
arr="monday";
```

you first make `arr` point to a *single* character you allocate. Then you reassign `arr` and make it point somewhere else (to the first character of the array for the literal `"monday"`). That leads to a *leak* as the original memory you allocate is lost and can no longer be accessed.

As for

```
char *newArr=new char[3];
newArr[0]="monday";
```

Here you make `newArr` point to an "array" of three single characters, and then try to make the *single character* `newArr[0]` point to the string literal.

---

A little differently, what you try to do with

```
char* arr = new char;
```

is basically equivalent to

```
char arr[1];
```

And with

```
char* newArr = new char[3];
```

That's equivalent to

```
char newArr[3];
```

---

The *standard* way to solve your problem is of course to use the C++ standard [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class. Like for example

```
std::string arr;
arr = "monday";
```

And together with a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for the second:

```
std::array<std::string, 3> newArr;
newArr[0] = "monday";
```

---

Finally, about the difference between `arr` and `newArr[0]`. One is a pointer to `char`, of type `char*`. The other is a `char` (but `newArr` is a pointer to `char` just like `arr`).

Comment: why compiler even allows to reassign arr, if I may ask

Comment: @awashima Because it's not invalid? You can make it point to anywhere if you want to. C++ doesn't hold your hand, if you want to [shoot yourself in the foot](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+in+the+foot) you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

> aren't they both pointers to address of first letter?

Yes, both `arr` and `newArr` are pointers to the initial character in a C-style string. However, `newArr[0]` is not a pointer at all, so C++ does not let you assign a `const char*` pointer to it.

If you want to get a pointer to the initial character of `newArr`, you need to use operator `&`, i.e. `&newArr[0]`. You wouldn't be able to assign it, but you would be able to print it:

```
const char *newArr = "monday";
cout <<  newArr[0] << endl; // prints m
cout << &newArr[0] << endl; // prints monday
```

Note that both assignments of `new` in your code produce memory leaks, because you overwrite the value produced by `new` with another one without releasing the allocated memory.

Comment: delete arr; delete [] newArr;
should be added?

Comment: @awashima This would be true if your code used the allocated values in any way. However, it does not: you overwrite the allocated pointers right away. That's why a better alternative is to remove `new` altogether, because your program does not use its results.

Comment: ok, i get it, i just wanted two, what to me seemed semanticly identical, chunks of code...but if i do something like this(assignment was to dynamiclly allocate array and fill it with days in week) { char (*arr)[12]=new char[7][12]; strcpy(arr[0],"monday"); strcpy(arr[1],"tuesday"); strcpy(arr[2],"wednesday"); strcpy(arr[3],"thursday"); strcpy(arr[4],"friday"); strcpy(arr[5],"saturday"); strcpy(arr[6],"sunday"); for(int i=0;i<7;i++){ cout<<arr[i]<<endl; } delete [] arr;} are the locations allocatted at the start used with strcpy() or, i mean is there memory leak

Comment: @awashima The code from your comment is correct, it does not have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the difference between "arr" and "newArr[0]"

Short answer, unlike `arr`, `newArr[0]` is not a pointer but instead can hold a character. `newArr[i]` is same as `*(newArr + i)`. You are trying to make place a string onto a character type.